# How can I get a width/height of Dialog with FILL_PARENT layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity with

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

to show it as float window. Also I have a line

```
getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

And I need a width/height of this window to show content correctly.

I've tested four options and did not get an answer:

```
//1 
int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

//2 
int width = getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth();

//3 
getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);

//4 
int width = getWindow().getAttributes().width;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

use this function:

```
private int getting_screen_width(Dialog dialog) 
    { 
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
     dialog.getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    String width = ""+dm.widthPixels ;
    dm = null;
       return (Integer.parseInt(width));
```

this return the value of the screen width

Comment: Your function returns screen-width, but I need a width of popup window. Activity with dialog style shown as popup window with W (and H) less than screen-W (-H) 10px approximately.

Comment: The last edits also do the same: returns screen-width but I need actual window width )

Comment: also is you use dialog.getWindow() with your current dialog? Strange i will also test it on my project soon